# heroku) nuxt settings - config vars : Unknown Error

Tags: heroku, nuxt.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4jUg.png)

I tryed to add config vars,  KEY : HOST,  VALUE : 0.0.0.0

but error message

"Item could not be updated: Unknown Error, Please contact support

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. `0.0.0.0` is used to indicate to accept any IP address, you shouldn't need to do that as ConfigVar. I suggest explaining what you are trying to do and post some code which is relevant

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.